# Is the SDP a=crypto attribute relevant when DTLS-SRTP is used?

Tags: webrtc, sdp, dtls

The a=crypto attribute in RFC 4568 has a separate section 9.2. for SRTP "Crypto" Attribute Grammar. What it basically includes is a list of attribute values required for encrypting media (crypto suite, method, session params, keys, MKI...).

However, DTLS-SRTP also does in its handshake protocol ([RFC 5764 - SRTP Extension for DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5764)) what is done via SDP in an offer-answer protocol. So, is it correct to say that where DTLS-SRTP is used, the a=crypto: attribute is not used. For example, does webRTC offer-answer SDP use the "a=crypto:" attribute as DTLS-SRTP is a must for webRTC?

Informational RFC "[SDP for webRTC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-sdp-11)" also does not throw any light on this issue.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct, a=crypto is only used for SDES. When using DTLS-SRTP, the keys are derived from the DTLS handshake instead.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The inclusion/mention of a=crypto in the "SDP for webRTC" RFC is what got me confused as I did not see any a=crypto in the webRTC SDPs.

Comment: that is probably left over from the time (back in 2013) when it was still up for discussion whether webrtc should support SDES or not...